# How to read all routes dynamically in node.js

Tags: node.js, routes

I am trying to read all routes in my app.js  file from './routes' folder,but
gettingerror:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

```
           import express from "express";
           import fs from "fs";
           const app = express();
           fs.readdir('./routes', (err, fs) => {
           fs.forEach(file => {
           app.use('/', require('./routes/' + file))
                             });
                   })
          export default app
```

Comment: Do you want to get all the routes attached to the express instance? Or do you want to add dynamically your routes?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**sync**

```
fs.readdirSync('/some/path/routes').forEach(function(file) {
  app.use('/', require(`/some/path/routes/` + file));
});
```

**async**

```
fs.readdir('/some/path/routes', function(err, files){
  files.forEach(function(file){
    app.use('/', require(`/some/path/routes/` + file));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `fs.readdirSync` because the server is not yet started.

```
fs.readdir(`${__dirname}/routes`, (err, files) => {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else {
    files.forEach(file => {
      app.use('/', require(`${__dirname}/routes` + file));
    })
  }
})
```

You can use fspromise and import to handle using promise.

```
import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
export const init = async () => {
  const files = await fsPromises.readdir(`${__dirname}/routes`);
  const router = Router();
  const createRoute = async (file) => {
    const route = await import(`./routes/${file}`);
    router.use("/", route.default);
  };
  await Promise.all(files.map(createRoute));
  return router;
}

// app.js
import {init} from "./routes";
const app = express();

(async() => {
 await init();
//  Start server
})();
```

I would suggest doing like below. You will have more control over routes. You can do customization on routes bases if needed.

ex. /v1 and /v2 etc..

```
// routes/index.js
import { Router } from "express";
import route1 from './route1';
import route2 from './route2';

const router = Router();
[route1, route2].forEach((route) => router.use("/", route));
export default router;


// app.js
import express from "express";
import routes from "./routes";

const app = express();
app.use("/", routes);

export default app;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul , could you please share some snippets how to do the same using import instead of "require" since i have added type:"module" in my package.json

Comment: @RohitRai I've updated my answer, you use this approach not tested but it should work